# ¿Cómo cambio el color de menú, en la clase Drawer en dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero cambiar el Color de el icono menú pero usando el `Drawer` no me lo permite.

```
drawer:
  Drawer(
    child:
      Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueAccent),

      child:
        ListView(
           children: <Widget>[
                  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: Text( 'Hugo Pinango',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
               ), //container
                 ),//drawer
```

No funciona en mi pruebas poner `Icon o Color/Colors` no he logrado ver nada en la documentación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunas opciones para realizarlo, la primera es la más complicada, sobreescribir el atributo `leading` del `AppBar` y agregar tu propio `IconButton` con la acción para abrir el drawer.

Si no quieres complicarte mucho, usa esta opción, asigna un `Theme` al `MaterialApp` y cambia el `primaryIconTheme`.

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
```

En ese ejemplo estarás poniendo el icono en color rojo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una de las maneras con las cuales puedes conseguir el efecto que andas buscando para un **Scaffold** en particular, ademas si quieres puedes cambiar el icono por defecto.

```
  Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.green, //Color verde
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                /* Acción al presionar el drawer (menú) */
              },
            ),
           ), 
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas fácil de cambiar el color si es que queres mantener el icono de configuración standar es en el AppBar.

home: Scaffold(
drawer: _menuPrincipal(),
appBar: AppBar(
***iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red)***

Simplemente en el ingresar iconTheme y ahí tenes la opción de cambiar al color que quieras.

Saludos.